# How do I increase the array and add a Gameobject to a new field?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a certain array that stores chunks of the world, and I need to increase the array through the script and place the chunk in a new field for the chunk. How can this be done?

I wrote this code:

```
public class WriteInWorld
{
    [MenuItem("Assets/Add To World")]
    public static void SetAsWmass()
    {
        GameObject[] selectedWmass = Selection.gameObjects;
        Debug.Log(selectedWmass);
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedWmass.Length; i++)
        {
            selectedWmass[i].GetComponent<Wmasss>().Chunk = selectedWmass[i];
            Debug.Log(selectedWmass[i]);
        }
        
        //world = Find.FindWorldObjectAsBoolArgument(true);
        //Debug.Log(world.GetComponent<World>().Chunk.ToList() + ":  :" + world);
        
    }

    [MenuItem("Assets/Add To World", isValidateFunction:true)]
    public static bool SetAsWmassValidator()
    {
        return Selection.activeObject is Wmasss;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you have got 2 options:

1. If you know how many items you will need to store in a container, you can use an `array`.
2. If you don't know how many items you will need to store, a [`List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-7.0) might be what you're looking for.